# how to give powershell line enough time to run the code and go to next line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

```batch
cd \
cd Temp\AwsEnaNetworkDriver

.\install.ps1

Restart-Computer
```

I'm using above powershell script to upgrade AWS ena driver in all EC2 windows servers.
if you guys know, when install/upgrading it - server goes offline for 15-20seconds and come back online. and if i restart manually - all looks good.

But if i use "restart-computer" at the end as above commands - it restarts and even after 30 mins ec2 instance does not finish rebooting. i have to force stop and start it and all looks good.( because 15-20 seconds of upgrade process does not happen, it goes to restart command straightaway after running the "install.ps1" script. )
even if i use the sleep command for 30 seconds before restart command, (15-20 seconds of upgrade process does not happen )

How do i write PowerShell, to give "install.ps1" to run for 15-20 seconds, then run next line either sleep or restart ? ?

Comment: How come you dont directly use the install.ps1, and edit for your requirements, rather than having a script that runs another script?

Comment: Add the line `Start-Transcript 'c:\ena.log';` to top of script - it will log all output. Maybe there is an error other than timeout? How do you plan to execute the script? If you have SSM setup (instance role and agent) it can be used to install ENA on 1 or many instances

Comment: Is install.ps1 spawning off another process and ending quickly?  What happens when you run install.ps1 directly by itself?   How long does it take to finish and return to the prompt?